# Importing excel using angular 7

Tags: angular, multipartform-data

I am trying to implement import functionality in my application. I am just curious to know how to create formData in key value pair. below is my code

```
onImport(event) {
    // generally we append the file in formData
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', event[0], event[0].name); 
}
```

But i need to append file in formdata in key value format
expected formData should be something like this-

```
     let formdata = [
        {
            "key": "file",
            "type": "file",
            "src": "/home/abc/Entity_Sample.xlsx"
        },
        {
            "key": "startDate",
            "value": "19/05/2020",
            "type": "text"
        },
        {
            "key": "endDate",
            "value": "19/07/2020",
            "type": "text"
        }
    ]
```

my method-

```
    onImport(event) {
       const formData: FormData = new FormData();
        const obj ={
        key: 'startDate',
        value: event.StartDate,
        type: 'text'
        }
      const obj2 ={
        key: 'endDate',
        value: event.endDate,
        type: 'text'
      }
     this.entityService.importExcel(formData).subscribe(
        (response) => {
         //file imported
      });
  }
```

Comment: what's the reason that you are sending the data as FormData?

Comment: I am trying import an excel data to my table.

Comment: why dont you just send the json data? the form data is not useful in your case if you dont send `file` object

Comment: the parameter `event` of `onImport` is file input change event?

Comment: o yes. That's file event . obj1 and obj2 was just for representation purpose. I just wanted to create an array and then append it to formData

Comment: so you want to send array of files to backend?

Comment: yes..I am sending the the data to backend and in response will get table data in json format

Answer (score 0):

You can append the files in the form data like this:

```
const fileList = event.target.files;
const data = new FormData();

for (let i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
  data.append('files[]', fileList.item(i));
}
```